# Stop User From Going Back To Being Logged In Web Browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a web app and when a user logs out and is taken to the login page, I want to stop them from being able to go back to the previous page (the logged in page) as they just logged out and this would be a security issue? I was wondering who I could do this in JavaScript? I would like it ideally to just reload the current page they are on the first time they hit it and then if they hit it a second time go to the last page where they weren't logged in. Or if thats not possible then to do what the standard practice is?

Here is what I am trying but its not working,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
    console.log('called')
e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
}
</script>
```

I get an error saying e is not defined

Comment: Share your code.  Questions on SO should have the code you are using so we can help.

Comment: Where is the HTML for `refreshed`?

Comment: Security/Authentication is usually handled on the server not the front end. Disabling the onload function would circumvent your security check here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either [prevent the page from getting cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) in the client. Or perform an ajax request on page load to check if user is logged in, in the backend and if not refresh the page.